# Javascript Slider that controls TinySlider - feels inefficient

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, user-interface

I feel like the main point of inefficiency is how I create "notches" and must loop through all of the created notches every time the value for the slider is changed.

```
function sliderLoop() {
    for (var i = slideNotchArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if ($(".slider").val() >= slideNotchArray[i].value) {
        console.log(slideNotchArray[i].slide);
        teamSlider.goTo(slideNotchArray[i].slide);
        break;
      }
    }
 }
```

It's an exponential nightmare as each call can loop through every notch object, and there can be multiple calls a second. This is the only solution I could have thought of though, and I am more than welcome to someone else's suggestions. I attempted to mitigate the severity by including a break once the first notch has been found, as to not loop through the rest, but I feel as though it is still quite heavy.

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-bush-h3xyz

My major concerns are in relation to

```
  function sliderLoop() {
    for (var i = slideNotchArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if ($(".slider").val() >= slideNotchArray[i].value) {
        console.log(slideNotchArray[i].slide);
        teamSlider.goTo(slideNotchArray[i].slide);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Fires slider loop every time the value changes, I had to use mousemove as .change() would only fire once the mouse click was relseased.
  $(".slider").on("change mousemove", function() {
    sliderLoop();
  });
```

The "change mousemove" event listener, calls sliderLoop multiple times a second. sliderLoop() contains a for loop, which could potentially iterate through many (10+) array index's. Calling a for loop which iterates through so many index's multiple times a second makes me believe this is an inefficient method of going about a slider navigation, however, I am at a loss as to how to improve the code while maintaining the functionality. Would you believe this to be an issue worth worrying about? If so, how could I go about improving this?

Answer (score 1):

A technique that would likely improve this situation is a [*debounced* function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). That way the function to be run will only run at certain intervals instead of each time the events occur.

From [the Blog of JavaScript consultant David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/):

> For those of you who don't know what a debounce function does, it limits the rate at which a function can fire. A quick example:  you have a resize listener on the window which does some element dimension calculations and (possibly)  repositions a few elements.  That isn't a heavy task in itself but being repeatedly fired after numerous resizes will really slow your site down.  Why not limit the rate at which the function can fire?
>
> Here's the basic JavaScript debounce function ([as taken from Underscore.js](https://davidwalsh.name/function-debounce)):
>
> ```
> // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
> // be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
> // N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
> // leading edge, instead of the trailing.
> function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
>     var timeout;
>     return function() {
>         var context = this, args = arguments;
>         var later = function() {
>             timeout = null;
>             if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
>         };
>         var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
>         clearTimeout(timeout);
>         timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
>         if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
>     };
> };
> ```
>
> <sup>[1](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)</sup>

That can be used to create a *debounced* function that only gets called at an interval - e.g. 250 milliseconds (feel free to adjust to your needs):

```
var debouncedFunc = debounce(sliderLoop, 250);
```

And use that function in the callback of the event handler:

```
// Fires slider loop every time the value changes, I had to use mousemove as .change() would only fire once the mouse click was relseased.
$(".slider").on("change mousemove", function() {
  debouncedFunc();
});
```

That could also be simplified to the following, since the extra lambda function/closure is pointless:

```
// Fires slider loop every time the value changes, I had to use mousemove as .change() would only fire once the mouse click was relseased.
$(".slider").on("change mousemove", debouncedFunc);
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function</sub>